# How to connect IOT devices to Android App(initial connection)

Tags: embedded-systems, android-development, networks, iot

**Background**
I am starting a new project, and I want custom IOT sensors for an app I am writing. I want to keep everything as simplistic as possible so the IOT devices wont be running any major software or anything, I want them to be as simple as send and receive curl statements(I know they will have to have something but for design I want to assume they are dumb as possible so I don't make assumptions).

**Question:**
So the one thing I am not sure about is how I will make the initial connection between the app and the IOT device without it connected to the internet. I was thinking about trying to set up a HTTP Listener on the app with the IOT Device set to make connection with "Default SSID" on start up if connection has not been created yet. I figure once that call is made the app can handle the rest of the connections.

I was wondering if this approach is valid and is it possible in Android?  Is there a better more standard way mainstream IOT devices make connections initially?

Thanks in advance :) Just don't want to end up 6 months in with a bad design approach.

Comment: Bluetooth LE is commonly used for this purpose. You can buy self-contained Bluetooth modules that handle all the connection issues, leaving you to focus on the functionality.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff yeah and pay 8k USD just to have that Bluetooth logo in your user manual. Needs must.

Comment: @JanDorniak: if it's a custom device talking to a custom app, you don't need to specify that it's Bluetooth; just saying it's "wireless" is sufficient. The device's manufacturer will appear (on a Bluetooth scan) as being the manufacturer of the module; but if you're happy with that, then there's no need to pay a fee. (Source: I've worked on a product where we did exactly this.)

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff good to know, I was not sure about this particular use case. So only FCC/RED then but that's unavoidable.

Comment: @JanDorniak: yeah, you'll still need to get the whole product regulatory tested, but you can at least avoid having to get Bluetooth certification, since you'll be using a self-contained certified module.

Comment: Since this was put on hold as off-topic try asking at the IoT stack (it's beta but quite lively last I checked) or the Electrical Engineering Stack.

Answer (score 2):

> so the IOT devices wont be running any major software or anything, I want them **to be as simple as send and receive curl statements** (I know they will have to have something but for design I want to assume they are dumb as possible so I don't make assumptions)

This would still require your devices to integrate curl, or at least to implement a lightweight HTTP capable service (which isn't possible without *"any major software or anything"*).
That's quite heavy, and too much resource consuming for most embedded devices.

I'd recommend you let them run them a different lightweight protocol (other than HTTP), communicating with a central service application at a server, and let the app gather data from this one.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I hadn't put much thought into the actual device yet and its capabilities. I should probably revisit before more design spec. Though I still think I am at a loss about how IOT devices make the initial connection before been added to a network though HTTP or not. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This largely depends on your IoT architecture.

There is usually a button which allows the device which has to be configured to enter a "configuration mode". Then  the phone either picks up a WiFi based on some conditions (SSID? MAC? Something else?) or connects via Bluetooth. Regardless of what you do at some point you have to have a device with WiFi and maybe Bluetooth.

It would be easier for Ethernet connected devices - then just plug in the cable, connect your phone to the same network, send a UDP multicast and listen for replies.

As for those lightweight IoT nodes running on a single battery they use different protocols such as Z-Wave, BLE Mesh or IQRF to name a few. WiFi is too power hungry. They have different ways of connecting to the network, usually involving starting a scan on the gateway and pressing a button on the device.

Also if you are going the low power route don't expect to use a text protocol. I've seen low-power networks where a single payload is just 19 bytes! And their throughputs rarely exceed 100 kbit per second for the entire gateway, including any network overhead. So a binary protocol is a must.